# When @Param = -1 filter with IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need help with my query:

When I send to the query a parameter with the value -1, I would like to filter with 'IN' statement, otherwise filter according the value.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
WHERE  (StatusId = CASE WHEN @StatusId = - 1 
        THEN 
        @StatusId IN (1, 2, 3) 
        ELSE 
        StatusId = @StatusId  END)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* that has to return a value of a specific type. And if you go searching, you'll discover that SQL Server doesn't have a `boolean` data type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your example, as the following:

```
WHEN @StatusId = - 1 THEN  @StatusId IN (1, 2, 3)
```

... won't do anything since if `@StatusId = -1`, it won't be `in (1, 2, 3)`.

Anywhos, you can just use `OR` and nested parentheses:

```
WHERE  (StatusId IN (1, 2, 3)  AND @StatusId = -1)
        OR (StatusId = @StatusId AND @StatusId <> -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `CASE` statement for this, you can just use a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 
(
    @StatusId = -1 AND StatusId IN (1, 2, 3) 
) 
OR
(
    StatusId = @StatusId AND @StatusId <> -1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `CASE`. You can do it directly like this:

```
WHERE 
(@StatusId = -1 AND StatusId IN (1, 2, 3) ) 
OR
(StatusId = @StatusId AND @StatusId <> -1)
```

OR if you want to use `CASE` you can do like this:

```
WHERE StatusId IN 
(CASE @StatusId 
 WHEN -1 THEN 1,2,3 
 ELSE @StatusId 
END)
```